# What is the format of the DataType property for a DataTemplate or HierarchicalDataTemplate in WPF?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I am trying to understand what the format is for the DataType parameter for a DataTemplate or a HierarchicalDataTemplate. There are lots of examples scattered throughout the internet that I can copy and get working, but I don't understand what my options are.

For example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:DepartmentSelectionViewModel}">
```

I would like to understand what x:Type means. And what model:DepartmentSelectionViewModel means.

Or:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type r:NetworkViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
```

Again, it has x:Type. But this time r:NetworkViewModel.

Other examples will have sys: or local:. What do all these settings mean? How can I discover what other settings exist? (Is settings even the right word to describe them?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` and `r` refer to [XAML namespace mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml).

These are ofter found in the root tag or the XAML file and define the CLR namespaces in which the types (classes) `DepartmentSelectionViewModel` and `NetworkViewModel` are defined respectively:

```
<Window ... xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Project1" ... />
```

---

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class DepartmentSelectionViewModel { ... } 
}
```

You can define as many namespace mappings as you want.

`x:Type` refers to a type for which the implicit [DataTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview) will be applied, i.e. the `DataTemplate` with the `DataType` property set to `{x:Type model:DepartmentSelectionViewModel}` will be applied to all `DepartmentSelectionViewModel` objects in the `Items` collection of the `TreeView` when the view is rendered.